# Problems installing Memcache (PECL extension)

Tags: installation, redhat, pecl, memcache

I have installed memcached fine, and now I will need to install PECL extension memcache. Im running RedHat x86_64 es5. The installation gives me this:

```
downloading memcache-2.2.6.tgz ...
Starting to download memcache-2.2.6.tgz (35,957 bytes)
..........done: 35,957 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Enable memcache session handler support? [yes] : 
Notice: Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' in PEAR/Frontend/CLI.php on line 304

Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in PEAR/Frontend/CLI.php on line 304

Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Frontend/CLI.php on line 304
building in /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6
running: /root/tmp/pear/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... invalid
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable memcache support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable memcache session handler support... yes
checking for the location of ZLIB... no
checking for the location of zlib... /usr
checking for session includes... /usr/include/php
checking for memcache session support... enabled
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 98304
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache.c -o memcache.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/memcache.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_queue.c -o memcache_queue.lo
 cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_queue.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/memcache_queue.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_standard_hash.c -o memcache_standard_hash.lo
 cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_standard_hash.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/memcache_standard_hash.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_consistent_hash.c -o memcache_consistent_hash.lo
 cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_consistent_hash.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/memcache_consistent_hash.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_session.c -o memcache_session.lo
 cc -I/usr/include/php -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/memcache/memcache_session.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/memcache_session.o
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/include -I/root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/main -I/root/tmp/pear/memcache -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o memcache.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/modules  memcache.lo memcache_queue.lo memcache_standard_hash.lo memcache_consistent_hash.lo memcache_session.lo
cc -shared  .libs/memcache.o .libs/memcache_queue.o .libs/memcache_standard_hash.o .libs/memcache_consistent_hash.o .libs/memcache_session.o   -Wl,-soname -Wl,memcache.so -o .libs/memcache.so
creating memcache.la
(cd .libs && rm -f memcache.la && ln -s ../memcache.la memcache.la)
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/libtool --mode=install cp ./memcache.la /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/modules
cp ./.libs/memcache.so /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/modules/memcache.so
cp ./.libs/memcache.lai /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/modules/memcache.la
PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/modules
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcache-2.2.6/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6" install
Installing shared extensions:     /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
running: find "/root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6" | xargs ls -dils
361232   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jan 28 10:47 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6
361263   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jan 28 10:47 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6/usr
361264   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jan 28 10:47 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6/usr/lib
361265   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jan 28 10:47 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6/usr/lib/php
361266   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jan 28 10:47 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6/usr/lib/php/extensions
361267   4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jan 28 10:47 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
361262 236 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 235575 Jan 28 10:47 /root/tmp/pear-build-root/install-memcache-2.2.6/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so

Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/memcache-2.2.6
Extension memcache enabled in php.ini
The memcache.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

I tried as well to install this extension "memcached 1.0.2 (PHP extension for interfacing with memcached via libmemcached library)" but it failed:

```
downloading memcached-1.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download memcached-1.0.2.tgz (22,724 bytes)
........done: 22,724 bytes
4 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /root/tmp/pear-build-root/memcached-1.0.2
running: /root/tmp/pear/memcached/configure
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... invalid
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable memcached support... yes, shared
checking for libmemcached... yes, shared
checking whether to enable memcached session handler support... yes
checking whether to enable memcached igbinary serializer support... no
checking for ZLIB... yes, shared
checking for zlib location... /usr
checking for session includes... /usr/include/php
checking for memcached session support... enabled
checking for memcached igbinary support... disabled
checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: memcached support requires libmemcached. Use --with-libmemcached-dir=
to specify the prefix where libmemcached headers and library are located ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/memcached/configure' failed The memcached.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

Is there a kind soul out there that can solve this puzzle?

Comment: I am having this issue too. Checking for libmemcached location... configure: error: memcached support requires libmemcached. Use --with-libmemcached-dir=<DIR> to specify the prefix where libmemcached headers and library are located
ERROR: `/var/cache/php-pear/memcached-1.0.2/configure' failed

Answer (score 2):

Install libmemcached-devel

```
# yum install libmemcached-devel
```

Comment: I got this when running it: No package libmemcached-devel.i686 available.

Comment: This is right except for two things. 1) why .i686? and 2) the package is not in the base RHEL repo. It's in EPEL as `memcached-devel`, though.

Comment: I installed memcached-devel and performed a new memcache installation with no success. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Mistake that the same?

Comment: If you have installed EPEL (5, I don't think it is in 6), just install memcached from there: `yum install memcached` and also install the pecl package `yum install php-pecl-memcached` (there is also a `php-pecl-memcache`, see http://serverfault.com/questions/63383/memcache-vs-memcached for the differences )

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit the same snag. If you actually look at the install log for `memcache`, you'll notice that it compiles and installs it in the following directory:

> **`/usr/lib`**`/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so`

Yet, Apache tries to load the extension from the following location:

> **`/usr/local/lib`**`/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so`

Seems like it is a bug with WHM. What you can do is create a link and restart Apache.

```
ln /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so

chmod 0755 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so

/scripts/restartsrv_apache
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error `checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: memcache support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located`, run the command:

`yum install zlib-devel`