# Cannot load Memcached in PHP on Gentoo

Tags: php, memcached, gentoo

I am using Gentoo Base System release 2.0.3, apache-2.2.21-r1, php 5.3.8-pl0 and memcached-1.4.5.
I have done the following:

```
emerge dev-php/pecl-memcache   
emerge dev-php/pecl-memcached  
emerge dev-libs/libmemcache  
emerge dev-libs/libmemcached
```

all install just fine. I have started memcached and can telnet on the port and run stats command. Of course, **I didn't forget to restart apache**.

Now, for the PHP part:

```
ls -lh /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext-active/  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Jan  6 09:58 memcached.ini -> /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext/memcached.ini  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Jan  6 09:48 memcache.ini -> /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext/memcache.ini
```

both containing **extension=memcache.so** and **extension=memcached.so** respectively.

```
php -i|grep memcache  
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/cli-php5.3/ext-active/memcache.ini,
/etc/php/cli-php5.3/ext-active/memcached.ini  
memcache  
memcache support => enabled  
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1  
memcache.chunk_size => 32768 => 32768  
memcache.compress_threshold => 20000 => 20000  
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211  
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32  
memcache.hash_strategy => consistent => consistent  
memcache.lock_timeout => 15 => 15  
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20  
memcache.protocol => ascii => ascii  
memcache.redundancy => 1 => 1  
memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2  
memcached  
memcached support => enabled  
libmemcached version => 0.39  
Registered save handlers => files user memcache memcached

php -m | grep -i memcache  
memcache  
memcached
```

So everything is pointing to the fact that memcache and memcached modules are loaded in PHP, BUT if I use a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` it doesn't display any as loaded modules, it only shows:
`Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext-active/memcache.ini, /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext-active/memcached.ini

session.save_handler    memcache    memcache

session.save_path   tcp://localhost:11211   tcp://localhost:11211`
the two values mean Local Value and Master Value.
Also, if I run a test code for memcached, like the following:

```
<?php
$memcache = new Memcache;  
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Connexion impossible");  
$version = $memcache->getVersion();  
echo 'Version: '.$version;  
$memcache->set('key', 'koreus', false, 10) or die ("Echec de la sauvegarde des donnÃ© sur le serveur");  
echo "Les donnÃ© ont Ã© stockÃ© dans le cache (les donnÃ© expireront dans 10 secondes)";   
$get_result = $memcache->get('key');  
echo 'DonnÃ© depuis le cache : '. $get_result;  
?>
```

I get the following error message:  **Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /var/www/test/mem.php on line 2**

Any ideas on this? I am new to Gentoo and didn't find anything special related to configuring memcached+php on it.
Thanks.

Comment: Silly question, but did you restart your Apache instance after installing the module?

Comment: yes, I did restart it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current situation is that memcache and memcached are correctly loaded on the command line from `/etc/php/cli-php5.3/ext-active/` but are **not** loaded by Apache from `/etc/php/apache2-php5.3/ext-active/`.

Assuming that the CLI versions of these files are exactly the same as the Apache versions, it might be worth checking `/etc/php/apache2-php5.3/php.ini` to make sure it is correctly including the files in the extensions directory.

Run `diff`s on everything under `/etc/php/cli-php5.3/` and `/etc/php/apache2-php5.3/`.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I had ``extension_dir = "/etc/php/apache2-php5.3/"`` activated in /etc/php/apache2-php5.3/php.ini. I disabled it and it's working. Thanks for healing 2 days worth of pain.

Answer (score 0):

The classic "memcache vs. memcached"... :-) These posts can help:

PHP memcached Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659035/php-memcached-fatal-error-class-memcache-not-found

[memcache vs memcached?](https://serverfault.com/questions/63383/memcache-vs-memcached)

Comment: Yes, I have encountered this already as I did search my error prior to posting here. That is why I have installed both Memcache and Memcached. Also, Memcached php module is not to be confused with memcached -> the daemon.

Comment: But have you tried uninstalling "memcached" from PHP (the module, not the daemon)?

Comment: why should I do that? Anyway, first I tried just with one module installed and it also didn't work, then I installed both. But fine, I will give it a try again.